# Grab a part on array (inside array) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, fetch

I need to grab data within array (inside array) that will grab only the second and the third rows of each line.

```
<?php

$salaries = array(
   //I WANT TO MAKE A NEW ARRAY FROM ALL THE SECOND AND THE THIRD ROWS 
               "a" => 2000, 1500, 3000, 1950
               "b" => 1000, 2300, 2233, 2400
               "c" => 500 , 6590, 1024, 2048
   //FOR EXAMPLE RESULTS IN THIS CASE WOULD BE :
   //$newarray = array(1500,3000,2300,2233,6590,2048);
      );

?>
```

If there is no direct command for that loops would be fine :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all, your array declaration isn't syntactically valid.**

If you meant it to be a multi-dimensionl array as follows:

```
$salaries = array(
   "a" => array(2000, 1500, 3000, 1950),
   "b" => array(1000, 2300, 2233, 2400),
   "c" => array(500 , 6590, 1024, 2048)
);
```

Then, this can be done using two loops. In the first loop, loop through all the sub-arrays. Loop through the values in each sub-array, check if the value is second or third. If so, add it to the new array:

```
foreach ($salaries as $key => $arr) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
        if ($i == 1 || $i == 2) {
            $result[$key][] = $arr[$i];
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102002)

---

For completeness, I'm going to add the solution for the case when the values are **comma-separated *strings***, not arrays:

```
$salaries = array(
   "a" => '2000, 1500, 3000, 1950',
   "b" => '1000, 2300, 2233, 2400',
   "c" => '500 , 6590, 1024, 2048'
);
```

The logic is exactly the same, but instead of accessing the inner array elements directly, you'll have to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to create an array of the values. Then use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get the second and third elements, and create a new array from it:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($salaries as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode(', ', $value);
    $slice[$key] = array_slice($pieces, 1, 2);
    $result = array_merge($result, $slice);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102007)

Comment: Well this is working perfectly ! I was wondering how come there is no direct clean PHP command for that task and I would be happy to know that I'm wrong here :)

Comment: Opps... I'm sorry I didn't asked it as I wanted to.

The results should be :

$newarray = array(
               "a" => 1500, 3000
               "b" => 2300, 2233
               "c" => 6590, 1024
      );

Comment: @user3301364: Happy to have helped!